# C# COM+ service failing to accept event registration from C# client

Tags: c#, c++, com+, dcom

Basically, I have a C++ ATL DCOM service that I am trying to replace with a C# COM+ service, and am having issues when trying to register my event. I was able to reproduce the problem with the following example

MyInterface.idl:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(993D13F8-5752-4046-9179-3BABD1513A8F),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface MyInterface : IDispatch
{
    HRESULT MyFunc1([in] BSTR lid);
};
[
    uuid(841E7E02-2ED3-412B-928B-F9C01CE300CE),
    version(1.0)
]
library MyInterfaceLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid(6BFA2661-5286-4C7A-973B-5BD14A654B6D)
    ]
    dispinterface MyInterfaceEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(1)] HRESULT MyEvent1([in] BSTR message);
    };
    [
        uuid(0E10489A-4BD0-47FF-9739-843DF8072B0E)
    ]
    coclass MyInterfaceImpl
    {
        [default] interface MyInterface;
        [default, source] dispinterface MyInterfaceEvents;
    };
};
```

I use this IDL to generate my C++ and .Net interop libraries. The interop library is GACed and the native DLLs are registered OK as far as I can tell.

MyComServerCPP.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols
#include "MyInterface.h"
#include "_MyInterfaceEvents_CP.h"

using namespace ATL;

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyComServer :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CMyComServer, &CLSID_MyInterfaceImpl>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CMyComServer>,
    public CProxy_MyInterfaceEvents<CMyComServer>,
    public IDispatchImpl<MyInterface, &IID_MyInterface, &LIBID_MyInterfaceLibrary, 1, 0>,
    public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&__uuidof(MyInterfaceImpl), &__uuidof(MyInterfaceEvents)>
{
public:
    CMyComServer()
    {
    }

    DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYINTERFACEIMPL)
    DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON(CMyComServer)

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMyComServer)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(MyInterface)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo2)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo)
    END_COM_MAP()

    BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(CMyComServer)
        CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(MyInterfaceEvents))
    END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()
    
    STDMETHOD(InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo)(REFIID riid);

    STDMETHOD(MyFunc1)(BSTR message);
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(MyInterfaceImpl), CMyComServer);
```

This is similar to how my C++ ATL DCOM service is setup, and this works in my testing still.

MyComServer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using MyExample.Interop;

namespace MyExample
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("7A41F23E-B73A-40E4-A1B7-54B120B5923E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(MyInterfaceEvents))]
    [ProgId("MyExample.MyComServer")]
    public class MyComServer : ServicedComponent, MyInterface, MyInterfaceEvents_Event
    {
        public event MyInterfaceEvents_MyEvent1EventHandler MyEvent1;

        public void MyFunc1(string message)
        {
            MyEvent1?.Invoke("MyComServer: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my C# COM+ service that isn't working. Whenever I try to register my event handler in the below client it gives me this error:

```
An Exception was encountered: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyComClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.LoadAssemblyFromString(String assemblyName)
   at System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ComponentSerializer.UnmarshalFromBuffer(Byte[] b, Object tp)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ComponentServices.ConvertToMessage(String s, Object tp)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent.RemoteDispatchHelper(String s, Boolean& failed)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent.System.EnterpriseServices.IRemoteDispatch.RemoteDispatchNotAutoDone(String s)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.IRemoteDispatch.RemoteDispatchNotAutoDone(String s)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.RemoteServicedComponentProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyExample.Interop.MyInterfaceEvents_Event.add_MyEvent1(MyInterfaceEvents_MyEvent1EventHandler )
   at MyExample.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\zzsupport\source\repos\MyExample\MyComClient\Program.cs:line 19
```

MyComClient.cs:

```
using System;

using MyExample.Interop;

namespace MyExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(@"MyExample.MyComServer", true);
                //Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(@"MyExample.MyComServerCPP", true);
                MyInterface instance = (MyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                MyInterfaceEvents_Event ev = (MyInterfaceEvents_Event)instance;

                ev.MyEvent1 += Ev_MyEvent1;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                instance.MyFunc1("Hello?");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Exception was encountered: " + ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Ev_MyEvent1(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ev_MyEvent1: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: How can you writeline and readline from a service?  Your service is terminating because of an exception.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about the reading/writing. The exception is telling me that it is trying to load the client for some reason in the service, which it shouldn't be doing AFAIK.

Comment: The error is from the I/O Library "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"  There is nothing in the code that is using the library except the reads and writes.

Comment: Right, it's trying to load the client from the server, which is not right at all.

Comment: You server has to send a response back to the client with the error message.  Not display in server.

Comment: You are failing a Proxy Issue or a deserialization issue. Your client is connecting to the server over HTTP.  First thing I would do is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help find issue.Why are you replacing old working code?Is code using HTTP (non secure) or HTTPS (secure).  HTTPS uses TLS for authentication. TLS is sent before the HTTP request.  So I would start by taking working c++ and check if you are using TLS and version of TLS which you will see in sniffer.  The take failing code and see if you see request.  If no request than TLS is failing, otherwaise get status of response.

Comment: So this is DCOM/COM+ using RPC... And all local at the moment.

Comment: Everything I said still applies locally.

Comment: Last I knew DCOM/COM+ was dynamic after using port 135, and had nothing to do with HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: You can still use sniffer to see differences between working and non working.  Port 135 is not encrypted and would thing these days encryption is used.  Port 853 is DNS over TLS.